# $\ln(1+x+x^2)$ power series

Tags: power-series, formal-power-series

The problem is to expand this $\ln(1+x+x^2)$ around 0 in power series.

I'm confused. What should I use? ln(1+x) and do something with it?

Comment: You've guessed it.

Comment: Yes, the easiest way to do it is to find a similar function (you already did) and work from there.

Comment: $taylor(log(1 + x + x^2),x,0,20);$
$${{1}\over{20}}\,x^{20}+{{1}\over{19}}\,x^{19}+{{-1}\over{9}}\,x^{18
 }+{{1}\over{17}}\,x^{17}+{{1}\over{16}}\,x^{16}+{{-2}\over{15}}\,x^{
 15}+{{1}\over{14}}\,x^{14}+{{1}\over{13}}\,x^{13}+{{-1}\over{6}}\,x
 ^{12}+{{1}\over{11}}\,x^{11}+{{1}\over{10}}\,x^{10}+{{-2}\over{9}}\,
 x^9+{{1}\over{8}}\,x^8+{{1}\over{7}}\,x^7+{{-1}\over{3}}\,x^6+{{1
 }\over{5}}\,x^5+{{1}\over{4}}\,x^4+{{-2}\over{3}}\,x^3+{{1}\over{2}}
 \,x^2+x+\cdots $$

Comment: for $x \neq 1$ you can write $x^{2}+x+1 = (x^{3}-1)(x-1)^{-1}$ then $\ln(x^2+x+1)=\ln(x^{3}-1)-\ln(x-1)$ and carry on as you suggest.

Comment: Using the expansion of $\log(1+u)$ for $u=x+x^2$ leads to a mess (and I am surprised to see two users recommending this approach). Fortunately, $1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)$ hence $$\log(1+x+x^2)=\log(1-x^3)-\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{x^{3n}}{n}+\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{x^{n}}{n}=\ldots$$ Can you complete it, treating separately the cases $n$ multiple of $3$ and $n$ not multiple of $3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\ln(1+x+x^2)=\ln(1-x^3)-\ln(1-x).$$